# What does Iterable<?> do

Tags: java, iterable

We are doing a Music Player Project at School and we have a Playlist class but the class implements "`Iterable<Title>`".

What exactly does that mean? What I know is that "`Iterable <something>`" goes through the list of "something" is this right?

```
public class Playlist implements Iterable<Title>
```

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: Iterator is a pattern, that allows you to navigate through a list/array of things/objects

Comment: The use of `Iterable<T>` clearly stated in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).

Comment: An `Iterable` object is advertising that it can return an `Iterator` via the `iterator()` method. This allows clients to iterate through its elements.

Comment: Were the Javadocs that @Palle referenced not sufficiently explanatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration `class Playlist implements Iterable<Title>` means that the playlist somehow contains a list of titles or something similar.

It means that you can write:

```
for (Title x : myPlaylist) {
    ... do something with the Title ...
}
```

Technically, for this to be possible, the Playlist class needs to have a method `public Iterator<Title> iterator()` so Java knows how to do the loop over all Titles of the Playlist. And the `<Title>` tells Java that the elements for the loop are Title objects, not numbers, Strings, Playlists or whatever.

Generally, `implements X<Y>` means that your class has all the methods that X defines, and that some of these methods don't have fixed types, but some variable aspects, where you want to have the type Y used.

The interface `Iterator<T>` defines the method `public Iterator<T> iterator()` with T being the variable part of the interface. As Playlist implements Iterator, you get a concrete version of the method `public Iterator<Title> iterator()` , which allows you to loop over the Titles.

Comment: I call into question the definition that `Iterable` establishes "a list ... or sonmething _[sic]_ similar." "Something similar" is exactly what the question is asking about, and getting a sequence of events from an external source, one use case for `Iterable`, isn't much like a list. This answer should have attacked the central issue in the question. Simply restating what an interface is doesn't provide much help.

Comment: Nice answer - perhaps consider removing the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

`Iterable` itself does nothing. it is an interface defining 3 methods (in Java 8). A class implementing `Iterable` must implement these methods (or use the default implementation).

Comment: Default "orchestration", a more accurate term than "implementation". Default methods (should) leave details of implementation to classes, handling only the orchestration of abstract behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

It's interface. From docs.oracle.com:

> `public interface Iterable<T>`
>
> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the
>   "foreach" statement, where T is the type of elements returned by the
>   iterator.

So the answer to your question - yes, your assumption is right.